# Adding different size text and images on the same line using Foundation 5

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

web design newbie here...

I've embarked on my first web design project and decided to use Foundation 5. I'm having a few troubles with the top of my website.. Unfortunately I cant post a picture on here of how i want it so ill try and describe it as best as i can.

I want the "Phone" and "Email" larger than the phone number and email address but all on the same line. Then I need the social icons to the right of the page, again all aligned.

I'm having trouble putting everything on the same row and having different styles for each character.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
<div class="row hide-for-small">

  <div class="large-4 columns"><p class"contact-top">Phone <span class="smaller">- 0757776856</span> <span class="contact-top">Email<span class="smaller">- luke@bodymetrix.com</span></p></div>

      <div class="large-1 columns">
          <img class="social-btn" src="img/facebook-btn.png" alt="Facebook">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-1 columns">
            <img class="social-btn" src="img/twitter-btn.png" alt="Twitter">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-1 columns">
            <img class="social-btn" src="img/pin-btn.png" alt="Pintrest">
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="large-1 columns">
            <img class="social-btn" src="img/google-btn.png" alt="Google+">
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.contact-top {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-variant: bold;
display: inline;
```

}

```
.smaller {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
```

}

I hope this makes some sort of sense, really hard to describe without images!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, some tags were left open so I fixed that.

Change:

```
<div class="large-4 columns"><p class"contact-top">Phone <span class="smaller">- 0757776856</span> <span class="contact-top">Email<span class="smaller">- luke@bodymetrix.com</span></p></div>
```

To:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
  <p>
      <span class="contact-top">Phone</span><span class="smaller">- 0757776856</span> 
      <span class="contact-top">Email</span><span class="smaller">- luke@bodymetrix.com</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

For the second part if you can update this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXqPE/1/) with the images so I can see what you are talking about (you can also see my changes there)

Comment: Also see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp for more general information about the ever useful Span tag.

Comment: Thanks for the first part, that works well. I'm struggling to add the images to JsFiddle. Basically I have 4 social icons, Facebook, twitter, Pinterest and google+. I want them all in a row, same size, on the same row as the email and phone. Just aligned over to the right hand side.